# Change TextView depending on time in TextClock Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, time

I'm trying to change the text of the `TextView` when the time on `TextClock` equals to `11:59 PM`
I tried doing something like

```java
 if(digitalClock.equals("11:49 PM")){
            tvOne.setText("TEXT CHANGED");
        }
```

but the `TextView` did not change so I tried using `OnFocusChangeListener` on my `TextClock`

```java
digitalClock.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                System.out.println(digitalClock);
                if(digitalClock.equals("11:59 PM")){
                    tvOne.setText("Text changed");
                }
            }
        });
```

but I'm not really sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: What is the type of `digitalClock`? I suspect that it is not a string, and if I am correct, it can never be equal to a string. Please, a [mre].

Comment: TextClock digitalClock;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to docs, TextClock extends TextView :

```
 public class TextClock
extends TextView
java.lang.Object
   ↳    android.view.View
       ↳    android.widget.TextView
           ↳    android.widget.TextClock
```

Use `textClock.getText ().toString().equals(someString)` to get text from yours TextClock and compare to string that you want.
And implement TextChangedListener to monitor changes in textClock:

```
binding.textClock.addTextChangedListener (new TextWatcher () {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                if (binding.textClock.getText ().toString().equals ("20:43 PM")){
                    binding.textView3.setText (binding.textClock.getText ().toString());
                }
            }
        });
```

This should work

Binding is [Viewbindig](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) feature, to bind data and views

Answer (score 1):

Use Alarm Manager to perform this task

In your onCreate Method

```
private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
private PendingIntent alarmIntent;
...
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 23:49 PM
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 49);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 1 day

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
if (day == 1) {
            //today = "Sunday";
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
            }
```

Create a receiver class

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                 tvOne.setText("Text changed");

        }
    }
```

add Permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" ></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" ></uses-permission>
```

Comment: What if I want to select the alarm to set the alarm managaer every sunday at 11:59 pm?

Comment: Will it still work if I added it in fragment `OnViewCreated`? and what is `AlarmReceiver.class` is it the  receiver class that you want me to create?  lastly, receiver class is just a java class right?

Comment: AlarmReceiver.class is a BroadCast receiver class you can read more about it here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts